# Inserting into MySQL using slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have a table called "KLIJENTI" in MySQL database on ampps localhost server. Table consists of 4 columns: ID_KLIJENTA - int, IME_KLIJENTA - string, PREZIME_KLIJENTA - string and ADRESA_KLIJENTA - string.
I followed tutorials on how to use slick to insert into and read from database, but it does not do what I want.

Here is my application.conf:

```
scalaTest = {
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Scala1"
user = "root"
password = "mysql"
driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
connectionPool = disabled
keepAliveConnection = true
logStatements = true
}
```

build.sbt:

```
name := """project4"""

mainClass in Compile := Some("HelloSlick")

libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.0-RC2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.10",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.187",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test" ,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.28"
)

fork in run := true
```

And here is my helloSlick.scala:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import slick.backend.DatabasePublisher
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._


case class Klijent(ID_KLIJENTA: Option[Int] = None, IME_KLIJENTA: String, PREZIME_KLIJENTA: String, ADRESA_KLIJENTA: String)

class Klijenti(tag: Tag) extends Table[Klijent](tag, "KLIJENTI") {
  def ID_KLIJENTA = column[Option[Int]]("ID_KLIJENTA", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def IME_KLIJENTA = column[String]("IME_KLIJENTA")
  def PREZIME_KLIJENTA = column[String]("PREZIME_KLIJENTA")
  def ADRESA_KLIJENTA = column[String]("ADRESA_KLIJENTA")

  def * = (ID_KLIJENTA, IME_KLIJENTA, PREZIME_KLIJENTA , ADRESA_KLIJENTA) <>((Klijent.apply _).tupled, Klijent.unapply)
}

// The main application
object HelloSlick extends App {

  val db = Database.forConfig("scalaTest")
  val mojiKlijenti = TableQuery[Klijenti]
  val q1 = sql"select IME_KLIJENTA from KLIJENTI WHERE ID==1 ".as[String]

  val q2 = mojiKlijenti.filter(_.ID_KLIJENTA === 0)

  println(q1)
  println(q2)
```

Before I run this code, I already inserted one row into the database through phpmyadmin, so both values q1 and q2 should print out real values but instead of that, I get this:

```
background log: info: Running HelloSlick 
background log: info: slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1@56300388
background log: info: Rep(Filter @1636634026)
```

My apache webserver and mysql are turned on, just in case someone asks..
Why am I not getting the real values?

EDIT:> Later on, I tried to execute following command `mojiKlijenti += Klijent(Some(5),"Name","Surname","Address")` and again, it compiler successfully but when I check my database in phpmyadmin, no record is added..

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the real values because you need to convert the Query into an Action by calling its result method and execute it.

```
val action = q2.result
val results = db.run( action)
results.foreach( println )
```

Comment: I just tried that code, it compiles, but it returns nothing, and nothing gets printed out as a result.

Comment: It depends of the filter `val q2 = mojiKlijenti.filter(_.ID_KLIJENTA === 0)` get rows with that value in the specified column.

Comment: I just added one more row into database with ID_KLIJENTA = 2 , and the first row had the value of ID_KLIJENTA = 1, now I changed my code to 1, and after that into 2, and still I get no results, and nothing is printed :(